# How can I prevent display of my website in the small sreen?

Tags: html, css

i want prevent show my website in small screens same as mobile or tablet...
and i want to show message in this screen that open my site in large screen

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Set width and height using media queries like this

```
@media screen and (max-width:360px) and (max-height:520px){
  body{
    display:none
  }
}
```

[pen is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMdRXq) with resizable window

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries:

```
//the css inside this block will only be applied to devices with less than 800px width
@media (max-width: 800px) {
     //add css here to show the message to open the webpage on a device with a larger screen
}
```

You can learn more about media queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

As you have tagged `wordpress`: You can add custom css where you can configure your themes.

Comment: i use wordpress site